# Which models and scene to use for a dungeon game?

Tags: 3d, models, ogre, jmonkeyengine, scene

I use jme3 with some builtin models and scenes and I've managed to put together a third person 3D scene.
[image]

I now want to program some attack and/or fights and I think that skeleton warriors and/or zombies will be ideal but how to get them? I don't know modelling, do I have to learn modelling, buy zombie and skeleton models, make them myself, download models from somewhere or something else? I'm currently using a builtin example scene that is like Quake 3 where I placed the ninja so that he can walk around and collission detection works which was the main project. Now the ninja can make an attack if I press the mouse button and he can jump if I press the space button and WASD controls the walking which is sort of slow but smooth. How can I try with another scene that is more like a dungeon? Is it the same as with the models, I must either design my own scene in a 3D program e.g. blender or use a scene like I do which is freely available?

I tried using a worldforge model for a goblin but it didn't render correctly:

```
com.jme3.asset.AssetLoadException: An exception has occured while loading asset: objects/creatures/goblin/textures/green/ogre.material
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:284)
    at com.jme3.material.Material.<init>(Material.java:116)
    at adventure.TownWorld.simpleInitApp(TownWorld.java:338)
    at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:225)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:129)
    at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Must specify MaterialExtensionSet when loading
Ogre3D materials with extended materials
    at com.jme3.scene.plugins.ogre.MaterialLoader.load(MaterialLoader.java:440)
    at com.jme3.scene.plugins.ogre.MaterialLoader.load(MaterialLoader.java:465)
    at com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager.loadAsset(DesktopAssetManager.java:282)
    ... 6 more
```

What does it mean? The offending code is

```
    Spatial model3 = assetManager
            .loadModel("objects/creatures/goblin/goblin.mesh.xml");
     Material mat_stl = new Material(assetManager, "objects/creatures/goblin/textures/green/ogre.material");

     mat_stl.setTexture("Green", assetManager.loadTexture("objects/creatures/goblin/textures/green/D.png")); 

             model3.setMaterial(mat_stl);
```

How should I use materials / textures for a model such as above? Now the mesh loads but there is no material and I don't know how to connect any eventual animation that come with the worldforge model.

I would really like to use skeleton or zombies, can you tell me how I should do it?

Any other comments / advice?
[image]
[image]

Comment: How to get art assets and errors associated with loading files are two completely different topics.  We don't allow "where can I find art asset" questions anymore since it's just a deluge of links that will eventually go out of date or not rated appropriately.

Comment: @Tetrad That's good to know since I actually thought it was the other way around that you didn't allow coding / bugs questions since those are more like regular SO question and that the asset links question would be a relevant question here. But I was wrong.

Comment: "bugs" questions are usually bad questions because the answer is usually "step through a debugger", but we allow programming questions if "a game programmer can give you a better answer than a general programmer", at least according to the [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opengameart.org. There are some great models there. Mind the licenses though. :)